# Jquery ¿como coger el texto de un parrafo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery como coger el texto de un parrafo que no tiene id cuando existe varios
en el documento.
ejemplo:

```
<p> este es el texto </p>
<p> este es el 2º texto</p> 
var texto=$('p').text();
$("#muestra").append(texto);
console.log(texto);
```

lo he hecho con este codigo, pero coge el texto de todos los parrafos:
con javascript se hacerlo ,con jquery no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En jQuery tienes selectores para poder seleccionar el primer elemento (con el sufijo `:first`), el último (con el sufijo `:last`) o el que se encuentra en una posición determinada (con el sufijo `:eq(index)`):

```js
$(function(){
  // Coger el primero
  var texto= $('p:first').text();
  console.log('Primer párrafo: ', texto);
  // Coger el último
  texto= $('p:last').text();
  console.log('Último párrafo: ', texto);
  // Coger un ínice determinado (por ejemplo el índice 1: 2º elemento)
  texto= $('p:eq(1)').text();
  console.log('Segundo párrafo: ', texto);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> este es el texto </p>
<p> este es el 2º texto</p>  

<span id="muestra"></span>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido para lo que queria